# Enforcing type with generics in typescript and sequelize

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, sequelize-typescript

I have an abstract service which is taking a repository in its constructor and getting data with Sequelize. The abstract service looks like this:

```
export abstract class BaseService<T> {

  public constructor(private _repo: any) {

  }
  public findById(id: string) {
    return this._repo.findById(id).pipe(
      map(res => Response.ok(res)))
    )
  }
}
```

where T is the repository type:

```
export class UsersInfosRepository extends BaseRepository<UserInfosModel>{
  public findById(id: string): Observable<UserInfosModel | null> {
    return from(UserInfosModel.findById(id));
  }
}
```

UserInfosModel is a sequelize @Model class.

Now this works fine, but the only thing is that I wish to enforce the type to

> _repo

with a generic T rather than use any. The problem is that the compiler won't recognise T as UsersInfosRepository and won't find the method findId. Has anyone got any suggestion on how to enforce the generic?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I found the solution

I changed the abstract BaseRepository into an interface:

```
export interface IBaseRepository<T> {
  findById(id: string): Observable<T | null>;
}
```

and edited the BaseService to accept:

```
export abstract class BaseService<T extends IBaseRepository<U>, U>
```

Where T is any Repository and U is any model.

```
export class UsersService extends BaseService<UsersInfosRepository, UserInfosModel>
```

hopefully this will be of help to anyone who like me struggled to find a solution including generics and sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `<T extends Class>`:

```
export abstract class BaseService<T extends UsersInfosRepository> {

  public constructor(private _repo: T) {

  }
  public findById(id: string) {
    return this._repo.findById(id).pipe(
      map(res => Response.ok(res)))
    )
  }
}
```

For more info:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: eh the problem is that even UserInfosRepository is a generic, so it would be extends BaseRepository<U (which should be UserModel)> but that doesn't work either